# How to change highlight line colors in search view in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers Version Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) on Ubuntu, default settings in both. The highlighted background in search view is the same as font color and I cannot see the whole selected line, see the screenshot. Is there any way to change it?

[image: eclipse search view screenshot]